# Terraform for loop to generate security groups with different ports and protocols

Tags: amazon-web-services, loops, terraform, flatten

I hope can someone can help? I'm a beginner in my terraform journey and from what i have discovered I need to use combination of dynamic function with flatten in order to achieve my reqs. My requirements are:

- create 4x different AWS security groups(diff description and name)
- each security group have same ingress and egress settings
- each ingress and egress should be created as a separate rule
- each rule has different port numbers
- each rule has different protocol to be used(e.g. TCP and UDP)

Jus to give a background, I need to create AWS FSx service(with managed AD) that will allow following set up access to and from FSx service: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/fsx/latest/WindowsGuide/limit-access-security-groups.html
Initially the security was done based on 1x security group for 4x different CIDRs with multiple rules but I ended up reaching AWS quota(60) for amount of rules per ingress/egress, so to not extend it best way recommendation from AWS support was to split each CIDR traffic as a separate security group.

So I tried to modify the code from link below but this does not seem to work: https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/flatten

**variables.tfvars**

```
security_config = {
      ports = [{
        tcp_port     = ["135", "389", "445", "636", "3268", "3269", "5985", "9389", "49152 - 65535"]
        tcp_udp_port = ["53", "88", "123", "389", "464"]
        udp_port     = ["123"]
        protocol     = ["tcp", "udp"]
        cidr_block   = ["10.1.0.0/28", "10.2.0.0/28", "10.3.0.0/28", "10.4.0.0/28"]
      }
      ]
    }
```

**locals.tf**

```
locals {
      security_rules = flatten([
        for port_key, port in var.ports : [
          for protocol_key, protocol in port.protocols : {
            from_port  = port_key
            to_port    = port_key
            protocol   = protocol_key
            cidr_block = security_rules.cidr_block
          }
        ]
      ])
    }
```

**main.tf**

```
resource "aws_security_group" "fsx_flatten" {
          for_each = {
            for port in local.security_rules : "${port.port_key}.${port.protocol_key}" => port
          }
        
          vpc_id      = each.value.vpc_id
          name        = each.value.name
          description = each.value.description
        }
```

I would like to have something similar output to:

```
security_config = {
          security_groups = [{
                name        = "sg_1"
                description = "security group 1 - primary site"
                ingress = {
                  from_port  = 53
                  to_port    = 53
                  protocol   = "tcp"
                  cidr_block = ["10.1.0.0/28"]
                }
                 ingress = {
                  from_port  = 53
                  to_port    = 53
                  protocol   = "udp"
                  cidr_block = ["10.1.0.0/28"]
                }
                ingress = {
                  from_port  = 88
                  to_port    = 88
                  protocol   = "tcp"
                  cidr_block = ["10.1.0.0/28"]
                }
                }
                ingress = {
                  from_port  = 88
                  to_port    = 88
                  protocol   = "udp"
                  cidr_block = ["10.1.0.0/28"]
                }
                 ingress = {
                  from_port  = 123
                  to_port    = 123
                  protocol   = "udp"
                  cidr_block = ["10.1.0.0/28"]
                }
                 ingress = {
                  from_port  = 135
                  to_port    = 135
                  protocol   = "tcp"
                  cidr_block = ["10.1.0.0/28"]
                }
                egress = {
                  from_port  = 53
                  to_port    = 53
                  protocol   = "tcp"
                  cidr_block = ["10.1.0.0/28"]
                }
                }
                egress = {
                  from_port  = 53
                  to_port    = 53
                  protocol   = "udp"
                  cidr_block = ["10.1.0.0/28"]
                }
                egress = {
                  from_port  = 88
                  to_port    = 88
                  protocol   = "tcp"
                  cidr_block = ["10.1.0.0/28"]
                }
                }
                egress = {
                  from_port  = 88
                  to_port    = 88
                  protocol   = "udp"
                  cidr_block = ["10.1.0.0/28"]
                }
                 egress = {
                  from_port  = 123
                  to_port    = 123
                  protocol   = "udp"
                  cidr_block = ["10.1.0.0/28"]
                }
                 egress = {
                  from_port  = 135
                  to_port    = 135
                  protocol   = "tcp"
                  cidr_block = ["10.1.0.0/28"]
                }
                },
                {
                  name        = "sg_2"
                  description = "security group 2 - secondary site"
                ingress = {
                  from_port  = 53
                  to_port    = 53
                  protocol   = "tcp"
                  cidr_block = ["10.2.0.0/28"]
                }
                 ingress = {
                  from_port  = 53
                  to_port    = 53
                  protocol   = "udp"
                  cidr_block = ["10.2.0.0/28"]
                }
                ingress = {
                  from_port  = 88
                  to_port    = 88
                  protocol   = "tcp"
                  cidr_block = ["10.2.0.0/28"]
                }
                }
                ingress = {
                  from_port  = 88
                  to_port    = 88
                  protocol   = "udp"
                  cidr_block = ["10.2.0.0/28"]
                }
                 ingress = {
                  from_port  = 123
                  to_port    = 123
                  protocol   = "udp"
                  cidr_block = ["10.2.0.0/28"]
                }
                 ingress = {
                  from_port  = 135
                  to_port    = 135
                  protocol   = "tcp"
                  cidr_block = ["10.2.0.0/28"]
                }
                egress = {
                  from_port  = 53
                  to_port    = 53
                  protocol   = "tcp"
                  cidr_block = ["10.2.0.0/28"]
                }
                }
                egress = {
                  from_port  = 53
                  to_port    = 53
                  protocol   = "udp"
                  cidr_block = ["10.2.0.0/28"]
                }
                egress = {
                  from_port  = 88
                  to_port    = 88
                  protocol   = "tcp"
                  cidr_block = ["10.2.0.0/28"]
                }
                }
                egress = {
                  from_port  = 88
                  to_port    = 88
                  protocol   = "udp"
                  cidr_block = ["10.2.0.0/28"]
                }
                 egress = {
                  from_port  = 123
                  to_port    = 123
                  protocol   = "udp"
                  cidr_block = ["10.2.0.0/28"]
                }
                 egress = {
                  from_port  = 135
                  to_port    = 135
                  protocol   = "tcp"
                  cidr_block = ["10.2.0.0/28"]
                }
              ]
            }
```

Comment: What happened when you tried the code you shared here, and how did that differ from what you _wanted_ to happen? For questions like this it can help to include an example of what these rule blocks would look like if you wrote them out manually, so that it's easier to understand the general rule you're trying to implement.

Answer (score 1):

hope this helps to solve your problem

main.tf

```
resource "aws_security_group" "main" {
...
  dynamic "ingress" {
    for_each = var.ingress_roles
    content {
      description      = ingress.value["description"]
      from_port        = ingress.value["from_port"]
      to_port          = ingress.value["to_port"]
      protocol         = ingress.value["protocol"]
      cidr_blocks      = tolist(ingress.value["cidr_blocks"])
      ipv6_cidr_blocks = tolist(ingress.value["ipv6_cidr_blocks"])
    }
  }

  dynamic "egress" {
    for_each = var.egress_roles
    content {
      from_port        = egress.value["from_port"]
      to_port          = egress.value["to_port"]
      protocol         = egress.value["protocol"]
      cidr_blocks      = tolist(egress.value["cidr_blocks"])
      ipv6_cidr_blocks = tolist(egress.value["ipv6_cidr_blocks"])
    }
  }
...
}
```

variables.tf

```
...
    ingress_security_group=[{
            description      = "http from VPC"
            from_port        = 80
            to_port          = 80
            protocol         = "tcp"
            cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
            ipv6_cidr_blocks = ["::/0"]
        },
        {
            description      = "TLS from VPC"
            from_port        = 443
            to_port          = 443
            protocol         = "tcp"
            cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
            ipv6_cidr_blocks = ["::/0"]
        }
    ]
    egress_security_group=[{
            from_port        = 0
            to_port          = 0
            protocol         = "all"
            cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
            ipv6_cidr_blocks = ["::/0"]
        }
    ]
...
```

My purpose is to use **dynamic blocks expression** to iterate over ingress and egress objects whenever I add a rule

Terraform plan

```
Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution plan. Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  + create

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # module.ec2.aws_security_group.main will be created
  + resource "aws_security_group" "main" {
      ...
      + ingress                = [
          + {
              + cidr_blocks      = [
                  + "0.0.0.0/0",
                ]
              + description      = "TLS from VPC"
              + from_port        = 443
              + ipv6_cidr_blocks = [
                  + "::/0",
                ]
              + prefix_list_ids  = []
              + protocol         = "tcp"
              + security_groups  = []
              + self             = false
              + to_port          = 443
            },
          + {
              + cidr_blocks      = [
                  + "0.0.0.0/0",
                ]
              + description      = "http from VPC"
              + from_port        = 80
              + ipv6_cidr_blocks = [
                  + "::/0",
                ]
              + prefix_list_ids  = []
              + protocol         = "tcp"
              + security_groups  = []
              + self             = false
              + to_port          = 80
            },
        ]
    ...
    }

Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

Reference:

- https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks
- https://blog.gruntwork.io/terraform-tips-tricks-loops-if-statements-and-gotchas-f739bbae55f9